# ffmpeg - Redownload missing fragments to fix downloaded stream

Tags: ffmpeg, download, video-streaming, mp4, h.264

I have dowloaded an H.264 video stream using `ffmpeg -i <URL> -c copy <name>.mp4` but ffmpeg reports that it has skipped some fragments. Since the stream is still online (with, I suppose, all the fragments), is it possible to fix the downloaded file by fetching the missing fragments and adding them to it?

Comment: That depends on how you've downloaded the file. You may want to have a look if your download manager supports that feature.

Comment: Hi @mashuptwice, I've see the updated question. I've used ffmpeg to download the stream but any other tool would be good for me if it can fix it.

Comment: yt-dlp, wget, aria2c to name a few.

Comment: @mashuptwice I know they exist but I don't know how to use them to fix my file.